# How to populate intermediate table with 4 fields

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, html-select

I created an intermediate table where I go to collect 4 data, the id of the trainer, the id of the course, the id of the day and the id of the hour, I have to populate these fields with a select on the view

This is the view code

```html
<div class="container mb-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <span>In quale giorno viene svolto questo corso ?</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="day_id[]">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach ($days as $day)
                    <option value="{{$day->id}}">{{$day->day}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <span>In quale orario ?</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="hour_id[]">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach ($hours as $hour)
                    <option value="{{$hour->id}}">{{$hour->hour}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <span>Scegli l'istruttore</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="trainer_id[]">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach ($trainers as $trainer)
                    <option value="{{$trainer->id}}">{{$trainer->name}} {{$trainer->surname}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the create function in controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $image = Storage::disk('public')->put('courses', $data['logo_course']);
    $bgimage = Storage::disk('public')->put('courses/background', $data['bg_image']);

    $newCourse = New Course();

    $newCourse->name_course = $data['name_course'];
    $newCourse->lesmills = $data['lesmills'];
    $newCourse->description_course = $data['description_course'];
    $newCourse->logo_course = $image;
    $newCourse->bg_image = $bgimage;
    $newCourse->slug = Str::slug($data['name_course']);

    $newCourse->save();

    $newCourse->days()->attach($data['day_id']);
    $newCourse->hours()->attach($data['hour_id']);
    $newCourse->trainers()->attach($data['trainer_id']);

    return redirect()->route('courses.index');
}
```

This is the course model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name_course', 'lesmills', 'description_course', 'logo_course', 'slug', 'bg_image'];

    public function trainers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Trainer::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function days()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function hours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(hour::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is the trainer model

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trainer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'description', 'image'];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function hours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Hour::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function days()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is the day model

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class day extends Model
{
    public function hours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Hour::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function trainers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Trainer::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is the hour model

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class hour extends Model
{
    public function days()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function trainers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Trainer::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to make sure the data you are expecting to receive is actually what you are getting in your controller:

```php
dd($data);
```

Check the result from above to ensure `hour_id`, `day_id`, and `trainer_id` are set. If all looks good, the next thing I would try is changing the name of the  elements to exclude the [] - assuming you don't need the `id` in array format.

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <span>In quale giorno viene svolto questo corso ?</span>
    <select class="form-control" name="day_id">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        @foreach ($days as $day)
            <option value="{{$day->id}}">{{$day->day}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <span>In quale orario ?</span>
    <select class="form-control" name="hour_id">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        @foreach ($hours as $hour)
            <option value="{{$hour->id}}">{{$hour->hour}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <span>Scegli l'istruttore</span>
    <select class="form-control" name="trainer_id">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        @foreach ($trainers as $trainer)
            <option value="{{$trainer->id}}">{{$trainer->name}} {{$trainer->surname}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```